# What is the probability that the smallest of the two results is 3 given that the sum of the two results is 8?

Tags: probability

Two fair six sided dice are rolled.

(i) What is the probability that the smallest of the two results is 3 given that the sum of the two results is 8?

(ii) What is the probability that the sum of the two results is at most 5 given that at least one of the results is 2 appeared?

(iii) What is the probability that the sum of the two results is 7 given that exactly one of the two results is odd?

for (i) I got 2/5. I did P((3,5)or(5,3)) divided by p(the sum of the two results is 8) but my friend got a different answer so I am unsure.

for (ii) I got 5/11

for (iii) I got 1/3

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Your results are correct.  However, you should explain your reasoning so that readers of this site can detect any errors you may have made.  Welcome to MathSE.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated in the comments, your results are correct.